# typedefs and #defines are invisible for other files in XCode

Tags: c, xcode, typedef

First of all I am sorry for the title. I really did not know how I could describe my problem in a better way.

When using XCode, I have this problem that "typedefs" and "#defines" only seem to be visible for the file where they are written in.

Let's assume I have three files. **main.c**, **Foo.h**, **Foo.c**

**main.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef int simpleInteger;

#include "Foo.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    simpleInteger I = 22;
    printf("%d\n", Foo(I));
    return 0;
}
```

**Foo.h:**

```
#ifndef Foo_h
#define Foo_h

simpleInteger Foo(simpleInteger number);

#endif /* Foo_h */
```

**Foo.c:**

```
#include "Foo.h"

int Foo(simpleInteger number)
{
    return number*2;
}
```

When I try to compile this, XCode throws the error "*Unknown type name 'simpleInteger'*" in **Foo.h** and **Foo.c**.

To make this to work I have to include the line "`typedef int simpleInteger`" in **Foo.h** which seems not clean to me. However if I compile these files without the use of XCode, it just works perfectly.

> **How can I tell XCode to not complain about this and make it work like any other compiler would do?**

Comment: `simpleInteger` is defined only in the scope of the `main.c`. You need to understand scopes, and how `#include` (and other preprocessor stuff) works. It's not that complex, yet critical.

Comment: Ok, that solves my problem but it just seems more natural to me if it is defined in `main.c` since `main.c` also uses this `typedef`. Moreover it seems weird to me that only XCode is complaining about this but compiling with clang works even without a warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This needs to be in Foo.h, not main.c:

```
typedef int simpleInteger;
```